# How to launch a jar file on windows startup from the registry?

Tags: java, windows, jar, registry

I am trying to launch a jar file on Windows Server 2008 R2 startup.

I tried to add a key\value to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

I tried as a value several alternatives:

```
 java -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar
 "java -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar"
 c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar
 "c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar"
 "c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe" -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar
```

But none of them launched the program.

Can you advise please?

---

EDIT: Fixed exe to jar of course

Comment: is `jcm.exe` the correct file? try using proper capitalization and put both paths in quotes (Java *and* your jar-file). Note that your third command is running "c:\program" as a command (because of the space) and your fourth one as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a problem in the command line. I think it should be something like that last row that you have used but with jar and not exe.

```
"c:\program files(x86)\java\jre1.8.31\bin\java.exe" -jar c:\jcm\jcm.jar
```

You just need to test it in command line first and if it works it will work in the registry. You can also make a .bat file to start the java program and copy that to windows Startup Folder instead of using the registry.

The startup folder you can find here: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Comment: It should have been jre1.8.0_31 :-(

Comment: such typos are always hard to find :(

Answer (score 0):

**If it is Windows 10 then you may try this way-**

1. Create a batch file e.g. (my-batch.bat with below statements.)

   @echo off

   title my-app batch script!

   echo my-app welcomes you!

   :: *If your JAR contains GUI then use-*

   start javaw -Xmx200m -jar D:\Softwares\JAR\my-app-v1.0.jar

   :: *Otherwise use-*

   start java -jar D:\Softwares\JAR\my-app-v1.0.jar
2. Copy this my-batch.bat file at
   **C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup**
3. Restart your PC to execute your JAR on startup.

**Now, You may check your running JAR using Command Prompt with below commands-**

```
1. jps -l
```

> ***Output will look like-***
>
> 8120 sun.tools.jps.Jps
> 13276 D:\Softwares\JAR\my-app-v1.0.jar

```
2. tasklist /V
```